# How to fix KeyError: "None of [Index(['0', '3'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" in Pandas for headerless data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove two columns from a headerless .tsv file

```
df_train = pd.read_csv("train_sample.tsv", sep="\t", header=None)
df_train = df_train[['0', '3']]
df_train.head()
```

However, that gives me error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['0', '3'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

In some similar cases the problem was extra spaces or tabs in the column names, but unfortunately when I tried

```
for col in df_train.columns: 
    print(col)
```

There seems to be no extra characters.

Also, when I tried some other tricks, it turned out that the column names are of type int instead of str. But when I try to select the columns by int I only get some index errors.

EDIT: The index error was caused by a typo, so everything works as expected. This question should perhaps be deleted as `df_train = df_train[['0', '3']]` actually worked as expected, but in my case due to a typo caused index error that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are integers columns because `header=None`, so use `[0, 3]` instead `['0', '3']`:

```
df_train = df_train[[0, 3]]
```

Comment: Produces error: IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Comment: @AhtiAhde - what is `print (df_train.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: The bug was caused by typo in later script, removing the question as everything works as expected

Comment: Ah, well I can't delete this; I will accept your answer in 7 minutes.